# Почему не срабатывает скрипт фиксирования шапки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не срабатывает данный скрипт?

Есть проект, который собран на gulp. Скрипт подключаются следующим образом (см. на картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все скрипты прекрасно работают, кроме файла fixed.js, не показывает ошибки и никак не срабатывает. Данный скрипт отвечает за фиксированние шапки и выглядит вот так (на примере код)

```js
$(function() {
 let header = $('.header');
  
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    header.addClass('header-fixed');
   } else {
    header.removeClass('header-fixed');
   }
 });
});
```

```css
.main {
  height: 2000px;
}

.header {
    padding: 25px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 11;
  }
  
  .header-fixed {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="main">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__container">
    текс
      </div>
  </header>
</main>
```

Comment: проблема решена?

Comment: @highpassion нет, здесь работает, даже когда отдельно выносил например здесь jsfiddle.net/moiseev1788/m8q9ca1w/1 все работает, но при сборке он никак не реагирует. Может быть проблема в версии jquery?

Comment: пробуйте с 3.4.*, попробуйте fixed.js последним подключать

Comment: @highpassion, не-а, поставил версию 3.4.1, вынес код из файла, реакции никакой, не ставит класс к header? Возможно ли как-то на чистом js это сделать, вдруг поможет? Не очень силен в js

Comment: да, на чистом можно, но у вас есть вариант включить скрипт в html как `<script>` или вставить код в другой файл, который нормально подключается. могу на чистом переписать

Comment: Переписал на обычном js, попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

Добавил реализацию fixed.js на чистом JS.

У вас в CSS ошибка в имени класса `.header_fixed`

```js
 let header = document.querySelector('.header');
  
 window.onscroll = function() {
   if(this.pageYOffset > 1) {
    header.classList.add('header_fixed');
   } else {
    header.classList.remove('header_fixed');
   }
 };
```

```css
.main {
  height: 2000px;
}

.header {
    padding: 25px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 11;
  }
  
  .header_fixed {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="main">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__container">
    текс
      </div>
  </header>
</main>
```

Comment: Ошибку исправил, да, здесь работает, даже когда отдельно выносил например здесь https://jsfiddle.net/moiseev1788/m8q9ca1w/1/ все работает, но при сборке он никак не реагирует. Может быть проблема в версии jquery?